# Optimal method to add bootstrap into Angular project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

From what I gather, there are three different ways to add bootstrap > v4 into an angular-cli project. What is the optimal way of the three (or is there any more not listed below) to add bootstrap into a dev and production environment?

1. use a cdn/node modules folder and add a link ref to the bootstrap css stylesheet in the index.html file on the root folder
2. use a cdn/node modules folder and add a reference to the bootstrap css file in the styles section of the angularcli.json file
3. use an @import to import css from the node modules folder inside the styles.css file

Finally, is a CDN preferred or npm installing Bootstrap into node_modules and referencing css there?

Comment: I would go with way 2 since fewer requests are better in most cases.

Comment: not sure why this is getting down voted since i am asking folks what their thoughts are on optimal usage given the many different options that are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the best way is to follow the official angular cli documentation unless you have some restriction or some specific reason not to use it in that way -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Comment: Which is basically a combination of 2 and 3 (minus the cdn part)

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta wouldn't it just be #2 without the CDN? we would not be importing anything in styles.css with this approach

Comment: yes that is correct. Sorry, i meant if you are using scss, then you'll need the imports :P